# How to print a specific HTML element and not the full page in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, pdf, printing

Let's say I'd like to print (or convert to PDF) a particular area (e.g., a `div`) of a complex HTML page. How to do that in Chrome or Firefox? I didn't find a specific option from the "inspect element" function.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a quite an old topic, but here is what worked for me:

```
<div id="parent_div">
    <p>NOT to be printed</p>
    <div id="print_div">
        Print this!
    </div>
    <button id="print_now" onclick="PrintDiv('print_div')">
</div>
```

And the JS function:

```
function PrintDiv(div_id) {
    $('body').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#"+div_id).css("visibility", "visible");
    window.print();
    $('body').css("visibility", "visible");    
}
```

If you are not using jQuery, you can still change the CSS with:

```
document.getElementById("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById(div_id).style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: It is simple and work well.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By using a print only `media query`, which is a feature [introduced in CSS3](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Assuming it is identified by either an `id` or `class` selector, you apply `display: none` to it, and not `visibility: hidden`, since display controls not only the exibition of the element, it also controls the space occupied in the document, unlike visibility, which hides it but still lets it occupy its space.

So it should look somewhat like this:

```css
#container {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#display-test {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#visibility-test {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#display-test,
#visibility-test {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

#print-display-test,
#print-visibility-test {
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

@media only print {
  #display-test {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #visibility-test {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  #print-display-test,
  #print-visibility-test {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="display-test">
    This is a display test
  </div>
  <span id="print-display-test">
    This is going to show at the start of the page
  </span>
  <div id="visibility-test">
    This is a visibility test
  </div>
  <span id="print-visibility-test">
    This is going to show far apart from the text above
  </span>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="window.print()">
    Print this
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this one. i also find this here in stackoverflow :)

just try this this is a good example to solve your problem

function PrintElem(elem)
            {
                Popup($(elem).html());
            }

```
        function Popup(data) 
        {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

            return true;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
        This will be printed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a quam at nibh adipiscing interdum. Nulla vitae accumsan ante. 
    </div>
    <div>
        This will not be printed.
    </div>
    <div id="anotherdiv">
        Nor will this.
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')" />
</body>
```

Comment: Isn't there any integrated solution?